# Django aggregate top value of foreign key

Tags: python, django

I have Django models that look like this

```
class Solution(models.Model):
    score = models.IntegerField();
    data = models.TextField();

class SolutionAuthors(models.Model):
    sol = models.ForeignKey(Solution);
    user = models.ForeignKey(User);
    date_solved = models.DateField()
```

and I want to query to the most recent SolutionAuthor for each solution.

The equivalent SQL might look like this

```
SELECT * FROM Solutions s INNER JOIN SolutionAuthor sa ON sa.sol=s.sol
WHERE sa.id = ( SELECT TOP 1 sa_id FROM SolutionAuthor sa2 WHERE sa2.sol=s.sol
                ORDER BY date_solved )
```

Any thoughts on how to do this with the `annotate` feature or otherwise?  Solutions that reorganize the schema are welcome as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have > 8K rep, that means that:

- you know that **it is not possible to write filters on annotation**.
- you are able to write a `Solution` **[model method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-methods)** to get latest solution.

Here is a **sample solution with model method**, annotate in query is not needed because you can call method at any time:

```
class Solution(models.Model):
    score = models.IntegerField()
    data = models.TextField()     

    @method
    def last_solution(self):
        return self.objects.solutionauthors_set.latest('date_solved')
```

If this is not your approach may be because **performance issues** or because you can not include filters through model method in the query. If this was my app my solution will be to **persist last `solution author` into `solution` model**:

```
class Solution(models.Model):
    score = models.IntegerField()
    data = models.TextField()     

    #new persisted field:
    last_solution = models.ForeignKey('SolutionAuthors', null=True, blanc=True);

#keeping last_solution up to date:
#imports to handle signals:
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

#persisting data
@receiver(post_save, sender=SolutionAuthors)
def set_last_solution(sender, instance, signal, created, **kwargs):
    if created or instance.date_solved > instance.sol.last_solution.date_solved:
        instance.sol.last_solution = instance
        instance.sol.save()
```

This approach will improve performance for any query through last solution. The **disadvantage is the denormalization** of the database, but I think that must be changing in attitude towards this subject.